# Electron - Why do we need to communicate between the main process and the renderer processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I am relatively new to electron js and while I was learning I came across IPC. I understand that it is used to communicate between the main process and one or more renderer processes. By why do we need to communicate between the main process and the renderer processes. I simply could not picture a scenario. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing to understand in this?

Comment: I've added another answer to provide you with more details that can help you understand why communication between processes is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Caveat:** I haven't done any Electron work yet. So take all of the below with a grain of salt.

But I was curious about the question because I naively thought Renderer processes were more limited than they are (or rather, can be). Let's start with a quote from [the documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#main-and-renderer-processes):

> Electron has two types of processes: Main and Renderer.
>
> - The Main process creates web pages by creating `BrowserWindow` instances. Each `BrowserWindow` instance runs the web page in its Renderer process. When a `BrowserWindow` instance is destroyed, the corresponding Renderer process gets terminated as well.
> - The Main process manages all web pages and their corresponding Renderer processes.
>
> ---
>
> - The Renderer process manages only the corresponding web page. A crash in one Renderer process does not affect other Renderer processes.
> - The Renderer process communicates with the Main process via IPC to perform GUI operations in a web page. Calling native GUI-related APIs from the Renderer process directly is restricted due to security concerns and potential resource leakage.

So one example that jumps out is: What if you need to create a new window in response to a user action? The user action will be seen by the Renderer process for the `BrowserWindow` the action occurs in, but only the Main process can create and manage web pages. So the Renderer for that window needs to send a message to Main to tell it to open a new page (with a new Renderer).

Further down on that page:

> **Node.js API**
>
> NOTE: To access the Node.js API from the Renderer process, you need to set the `nodeIntegration` preference to true and the `contextIsolation` preference to false. Please note that access to the Node.js API in any renderer that loads remote content is not recommended for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content).

So by default, your Renderer processes are limited in what they can do, but you can remove that limitation by setting the `nodeIntegration` preference. But you're warned **not** to do that if your Renderer may render remote content. (See the [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) link for more about that.)

So that means if you want to do something like read or write a file, but you don't want to enable Node.js API integration in your Renderer processes, you'd have to have the Renderer send a message to the Main process (which can be validated and limited in scope) and have the Main process use the Node.js API to read/write the file (again, with limitations).

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. This gave the idea I needed to understand the need for IPC and why and when it is needed. Really Insightful.

Answer (score 3):

Electron apps are powerful because they allow us to use **node** in them. Node provides *many* different libraries and tooling that otherwise are unavailable when writing a web application. To help understand why we should be using two processes in Electron apps can be demonstrated with an example.

### Sample app

We want our Electron app to be a Windows explorer window, where the user can create, update, delete or rename files or folders. We create a new Electron app and build out our **main** and **renderer** process. Our **main** process makes the Electron app, and we put our logic in the **renderer** process to mimic an explorer window.

In our **renderer** process we create calls using the [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) library to read/create/update/delete new files and folders. All is well.

*Or is it*?

You decide to publish your app since you'll make big money on it in the market, and not a week goes by and users are reporting *weird behavior* after using your app. Apps on their computer don't work, some users are reporting their computer has blue screens - *what happened*?

### You didn't secure your app

*Never trust your users*.

For the very fact that you used the `fs` library in your app means that any user can easily F12 into your app, open dev tools, and have *all* of the access `fs` has on your file system. Essentially, you are giving bad actors [free rein of calculating numbers](https://blog.devsecurity.eu/en/blog/joplin-electron-rce) due to the lack of security in your app. I have written in more detail about this [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9920#issuecomment-575839738) if you are interested.

### How do we secure our apps?

A way to be better protected and prevent users from using node or otherwise imported-code in your app is to separate them into the **main** process. Instead of letting the **renderer** process use the imported code directly, the improved process is:

1. **main** process listens for an event
2. **renderer** process needs to use node module x, so it sends a request that it be used (this is IPC)
3. **main** process hears this request/event, and uses node module x and returns a result and sends it back to the **renderer** process via IPC
4. **renderer** process takes the result and acts accordingly

I'm the author of a [secure Electron template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) that has this [IPC messaging] built in, so you don't have to work from nothing if you have the opportunity to build a new app. I recently went around and [reviewed the current best Electron templates to use](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D) and there are other templates I would recommend if you are starting out. (Not *all* or the most popular templates are necessarily secure, FYI).

### tl;dr

By isolating the access to imported code/node libraries outside of where the user can access (ie. in the **main** process), you can place secure checks in your code in order that you don't accidentally give bad actors access to your OS.

Comment: Yes. thank you. I have been doing some small projects for the past few days to understand these things. This will be very helpful in the long run. FYI I think I liked the secure electron template I will definitely be using it in my future projects.

Comment: I don't get the security problem in your example. The Electron app doesn't have more permissions than the user who launched it. Of course, he could open the dev tools and delete a file using fs. But he could do that without the app as well. What am I missing here?

Comment: @z80crew - the risk is using external/remote code (ie. NPM modules) or malicious content. Since this code isn't something you wrote, you can't 100% be sure in what is actually executing. This is why the processes are separated. (If we did write everything, then we wouldn't need separate processes; is an argument we can propose). Hope this helps!